# Array no se preserva despues de AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo la siguiente función AJAX que se ejecuta dentro de un `for` para revisar si ciertos datos existen o no, si existen se aumenta en uno una variable, si no, se aumenta en uno otra variable:

```
 si = 0;
 no = 0;
for (var j = 1; j < parseInt(totalCajas); j++) {

     $.ajax({
            url: "views/ajax/OIT.php",
            method: "GET",
            data: { funcion: "funcion7", lote: valorLote, caja: j },
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(respuesta1) {
                     if (respuesta1.length == 0) {
                        no++;
                        } else {
                            si++;
                            arrayHay[si - 1] = j;
                            console.log("Local hay: ", arrayHay[si - 1]);
                        }

            }
      });
}
console.log("Cajas donde hay algo: ", si);
console.log("Cajas donde no hay algo: ", no);
console.log("Donde hay algo: ", arrayHay);
```

La cuestion es que los datos de `si` y `no` se preservan, no asi el `array`Hay, hasta lo muestra dentro del `if` del `si` con la linea c`onsole.log("Local hay: ", arrayHay[si - 1])`; pero ya afuera en la ultima linea del ejemplo aca puesto no tira datos, cual seria el error que estoy cometiendo?

Gracias

Comment: Prueba declarar el array en el mismo nivel que tienes a `si` y `no`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema con el que te enfrentas, se llama contexto.

El arreglo debe de estar declarado en el mismo nivel que tus variable `si`y `no`

```
si = 0;
no = 0;
var arrayHay = [];
```

De esta forma, cuando hagas la impresión al final, habrás modificado tu variable original. Si esa variable solo la declaras dentro del closure de success, solo sera conocida dentro de ese contexto, fuera no.